# how to call destractor for static class in c#?

Tags: static-constructor, explicit-destructor-call

Hi I am very beginner for OOPS please help me to understand this

how to call detractor for static class ? or else how to de allocate  memory for static class and methods and objects ?

Comment: What have you tried so far, please post some of your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

C# is a managed language. This means that .NET will automatically free memory with what's called a garbage collector when it is no longer being used. This is different than C++ for example, where you would need to explicitly delete an object in order to free it. In C++, the destructor for an object would be called when you call delete on the object. In C#, the destructor is called whenever the .NET garbage collector decides to destroy the object (Eventually, once you have no references to it and it is out of scope and .NET decides to reclaim memory)

Static classes can allocate static variables inside the class. Static classes do not have destructors that are called. So that part of your question is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

To allocate memory for *objects instances* you should use *constructors*:

```
  Object o = new Object();
  MyClass m = new MyClass();
```

*static field*s are allocated by .Net; so just declare them:

```
  public class MyClass {
    public static Object o = new Object();
    public static int i = 123;
  }
```

*methods, properies* are kind of *functions* in C, so they can't be allocated at all

*static classes* being *sealed* and *abstract* can't be created and so can't be allocated